# How to size a header for 3 openings along (non load bearing?) wall

Tags: framing, gable

We are reconfiguring the doors/windows along an exterior wall under the gable end. The original house had several windows and a 6' slider on that wall, all utilizing flat 2x4 headers.

We are going to be replacing what's there with a 6x3' window, a 6' slider, and 3' picture window.

We had someone come in and reconfigure the house rafters, add the collar ties, and remove the ceiling joists. My question is, with the removal of the ceiling joists, are there any new considerations for that wall in regards to the headers/requirements? The house is basically a 30'x25' single open room.

[image]

Comment: Have you had a licensed structural engineer look at what you've done?  From the photo and placement of the collar ties, it appears you have significantly undermined the structure of the roof.

Comment: Our contractor had his guy design it. But we haven't had a structural engineer look at it. If the structure of the roof is in question, then I will certainly get an engineer to look at it. They also built a 'double wall' along both load bearing sides.

Comment: "His guy"...  Hmmm, that sounds fishy.  You may want to check.

Comment: The original house was built in the 70's and had 2x4 rafters on 2' centers and 3/4" tongue and groove decking. They came back and sistered the 2x4 rafters with 2x8's, added the collar ties, and double-framed the load bearing walls and removed the ceiling joists/truss structure. Sounded like a good plan to me, but I'll get a SE to check it out.

Comment: I hope you are not in a snow zone , heck the weight of a heavy rain could just about flatten that place, the non load bearing wall would be easy but there is a lot of area and weight pushing out on those walls.